# Поиск количества вхождения подстроки в строке

Tags: алгоритм, строки, подстрока

Как возможно определить количество вхождения подстроки в строку, если подстроки могут пересекаться? Например: в строку "ааа" подстрока "аа" должна входить 2 раза.

Comment: Самый простой способ - найдя, смещаться на 1 символ и искать заново.

Comment: Но, не самый оптимальный))

Answer (score 1):

Приписать к паттерну P спецсимвол, который не встречается ни в строке S, ни в паттерне P, потом приписать строку S  (в которой нужно искать)

```
F = P + "#" + S
```

и построить для F префикс-функцию (Кнут, Моррис и Пратт на троих сообразили, как это сделать за линейное время).

Посчитать в значениях префикс-функции количество значений `n=Len(P)` для позиций больше `n`